# AngularJS - $rootScope.$apply not causing to refresh ng-model directives fed from descendant scopes

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a function which is wrapped in `$rootScope.$apply()` by the wrapping call (SDK.api):

```
SDK.api('/me', function(response) {
    //THIS callback, anonymous function, is wrapped by SDK in $rootScope.$apply
    $scope.form = {
       'first_name' : response.first_name,
       'last_name' : response.last_name,
       'email' : response.email
    };
    $scope.formEnabled = true;
    $scope.formFetching = false;
});
```

Actually, **this is a wrapper to Facebook JS SDK** (and **NOT** the plain FB object) and such function is called in the context of `$rootScope.$apply()`. I can ensure that because using `$scope.$apply()` at the end of such function raises an `"inprog"` error (i.e. I cannot call `$apply` inside a call to `$apply`).

This `$scope` object in the code (and so: the code chunk I wrote here) belongs to a controller I created for an `ngDialog` plugin. The ng-dialog looks like this:

```
        return ngDialog.open({
            template: url + 'partials/dialog-form.html',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain',
            scope: $scope,
            closeByDocument: true,
            closeByEscape: true,
            showClose: true,
            cache: false,
            controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                /* ... more ... */
                $scope.formFetching = true;
                $scope.formEnabled = false;
                $scope.success = false;
                SDK.api('/me', function(response) {
                    $scope.form = {
                        'first_name' : response.first_name,
                        'last_name' : response.last_name,
                        'email' : response.email
                    };
                    $scope.formEnabled = true;
                    $scope.formFetching = false;
                });
                /* ... more ... */
            }]
        })
```

and the `$scope` in `scope: $scope` is the scope from the main controller (My app has only one controller - it's not too big).

So we could say: `$rootScope` is parent of `$scope` in main controller, which at the same time is parent of `$scope` of the `ngDialog`'s `$scope`.

In the grandchild `$scope`, the `form` data is updated:

```
$scope.form = {
    'first_name' : response.first_name,
    'last_name' : response.last_name,
    'email' : response.email
};
```

And there's the template `url + 'partials/dialog-form.html'` which actually exists and gets rendered. The content is as follows (I will omit irrelevant code):

```
<div id="pedido">
    <form novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <!-- more code -->
        <table width="100%">
            <!-- more code -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="form.first_name" />
                        <span ng-repeat="error in errors.first_name" class="error">{{ error }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellido:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="form.last_name" />
                        <span ng-repeat="error in errors.last_name" class="error">{{ error }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Correo electr&oacute;nico:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="form.email" />
                        <span ng-repeat="error in errors.email" class="error">{{ error }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- more code -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- more code -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Assume the value for `ng-submit`, `ng-repeat` exist.

My **issue**: fields with `ng-model` are not being populated from `$scope.form`.

My **question**: what am I doing wrong? The form works as it should, and the data in the server side is received as it should. My only pain in the *** is that these fields are not being reflected when `$rootScope.$apply` is called - I need such fields prepopulated from Facebook (I have no issue retrieving such data from Facebook: I can be sure the data arrives if I log it with `$window.console.log`).

**Edit** Appendix: API Call

```
var SDK = function($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this._initialized = false;
    this._calls = [];
};
/* ... */
SDK.prototype.api = function(path, method, params, callback) {
    var c = this;
    this._makeCall(function(){
        FB.api(
            c.wrap(path),
            c.wrap(method),
            c.wrap(params),
            c.wrap(callback)
        );
    });
};
/* ... */
SDK.prototype.wrap = function(call) {
    var c = this;
    return (typeof call !== 'function') ? call : function(){
        c.$scope.$apply(call);
    };
};
/* ... */
FBModule.factory('AngularFB.SDK', ['$rootScope', sdk]);
```

Comment: Can you attach the SDK.api function to see what it's doing? Should make determining the issue easier.

Comment: OK I will include it.

Comment: I updated the question with the API

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It was not related to $rootScope.$apply.

A wrapped function with this:

```
SDK.prototype.wrap = function(call) {
    var c = this;
    return (typeof call !== 'function') ? call : function(){
        c.$scope.$apply(call);
    };
};
```

Did not proxy any parameter. `call` was passed to $apply, which passes the first parameter being the $rootScope itself. So I had to use "another layer" of closuring, and passing explicitly any param received by the wrapping function:

```
SDK.prototype.wrap = function(call) {
    var c = this;
    return (typeof call !== 'function') ? call : function(){
        /* copy the params into a new object */
        var args = [];
        angular.forEach(arguments, function(argument) {
            args.push(c.wrap(argument));
        });
        /* the applied call takes the params and creates a 0-arity function to be applied, which takes the task of calling the target function with the passed params */
        c.$scope.$apply(function(){
            call.apply(null, args);
        });
    };
};
```

So -as I supposed- nothing was wrong with Angular, but took a lot to figure that the passed param was not the expected one.

Solution: proxy the call **ensuring it is bridging the passed parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try creating the form object before the api call.

```
$scope.success = false;
$scope.form = {}; //try creating the object here
SDK.api('/me', function(response) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        //and update it here
        $scope.form.first_name = response.first_name;
        $scope.form.last_name = response.last_name;
        $scope.form.email = response.email;

        $scope.formEnabled = true;
        $scope.formFetching = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: if you wrap it in the $scope.$apply method, does that do anything?

Comment: Oh i see the SDK.api code now, looks like you're already doing this so nevermind.

Comment: that was, in fact, the knot of the question: why the $apply method does not seem to work (it is. the one who is not working is me xD, still dont know)

Comment: this breaks. $apply inside of $apply generates an 'inprog' error